# How can I view packages from a specific repository?

Tags: debian, apt

In my `/etc/apt/sources.list` if I add the path:

```
deb http://debian.meebey.net/pkg-mono ./
```

Can I view packages from this specific repository alone?

Comment: You may delete others except the repository that you want to search on in `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory. Then you can use apt search.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can examine the package list file(s) from that repository, they'll be in the `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory with names that start with the domain for the repository and end with `_Packages`.

It doesn't look like that repository supplies a `Release` file.  If it did, `aptitude` has support for using the `Origin` specified by a release file as a search term.  I have a Mint repository as a source in addition to the main Debian repositories, and I'm able to limit the packages that aptitude shows to just the ones from Mint by typing `l?origin(linuxmint)`.  But without a Release file, I don't know of a better method than just looking at the raw package list file.

Comment: Be sure to perform an `apt-get update` prior to searching `/var/lib/apt/lists`.  This directory on a brand new Nextthing CHIP was empty prior to performing the update.  I also couldn't install any packages until I performed the update.

Answer (score 7):

```bsh
# find the prefix of your repository
ls /var/lib/apt/lists

# list all the packages (replace "foo" with your prefix)
grep '^Package:' /var/lib/apt/lists/foo*_Packages

# hide the filenames so you can sort by package name
grep -h '^Package:' /var/lib/apt/lists/foo*_Packages | sort
```

Comment: Just FYI, this doesn't work inside a docker container, where all `*_Packages*` files are in fact `.lz4` archives. You could extract them and then run the command.

Comment: This worked for me. How can I get a list of just the "installed packages" from a specific repository? Your answer lists all the available packages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this repository is no longer hosting those packages

```
grep '^Package:' /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ondrej_php_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
Package: graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
Package: graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
Package: libgraphicsmagick++3
Package: libgraphicsmagick3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question is answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/132346/find-packages-installed-from-a-certain-repository-with-aptitude

In short, you can use the search features of `aptitude`. For example:

```
$ aptitude search "?origin(backports)" | head
p  0ad - Juego de estrategia en tiempo real de guerra en la antigüedad
p  0ad:i386 - Juego de estrategia en tiempo real de guerra en la antigüedad
p  0ad-data - Real-time strategy game of ancient warfare (data files)
p  0ad-data-common - Real-time strategy game of ancient warfare (common data files)
p  7zip - 7-Zip file archiver with a high compression ratio
p  7zip:i386 - 7-Zip file archiver with a high compression ratio
p  acpi-call-dkms - Kernel module that enables you to call ACPI methods
p  adb - Android Debug Bridge
p  adb:i386 - Android Debug Bridge
p  age - simple, modern and secure encryption tool
```

At https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html you can find  a summary of all the search terms provided by aptitude.

You will have to find out what is the appropriate parameter for your repository in the `origin` clause.